# Backbone form validation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is my first real backbone project that I trying to work on in my spare time to get a better feel for it all. The form validation has me a little confused.

I think I have the model set up correctly for it here:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "firstname": "",
        "lastname": "",
        "age": null
    },
    url: '/UMA.Service/Service1.svc/',
    validate: function(attr) {
        var errors = [];
        if (!attr.FirstName) {
            errors.push({name: 'firstname', message: 'Please fill in first name field.'});
        }
        if (!attr.LastName) {
            errors.push({name: 'lastname', message: 'Please fill in last name field.'});
        }
        if(!attr.Age) {
            errors.push({name: 'age', message: 'Please fill in age field.'})
        }

        return errors.length > 0 ? errors : false;
    }
});
```

I am not really sure how I should implement it on my view now though. I currently have it so that when I hit the submit button it does `.save()`, but I would like it to check the form for errors. If there are errors then prompt the user and stay on the page. if not then `.save()`.

Here is how my view is set up now:

```
var EditUser = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.page',
    render: function() {
        var template = Handlebars.compile($('#edit-user-template').html());
        this.$el.html(template);
    },

    events: {
        'submit .edit-user-form': 'saveUser',
        'click #new-user-cancel': 'cancelNewUser'
    },

    saveUser: function (ev) {
        var me = this;
        var user = new User();
        var firstName = $('.edit-user-form #firstname').val();
        var lastName = $('.edit-user-form #lastname').val();
        var age = $('.edit-user-form #age').val();

        user.save({
            FirstName: firstName,
            LastName: lastName,
            Age: age
        },{
            success: function(user) {
                router.navigate('', {trigger: true});
            }
        });
    },

    cancelNewUser: function() {
        userList.fetchUsers();
        router.navigate('', {trigger: true});
    }

});
```

I am sure I have to do some working around. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction of a good tutorial or help me out on the proper way to pass the errors to my view? Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [backbone-forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms) extension

Comment: you can subscribe on `invalid` event of `User` model and process result of `validate` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by keeping my model the same way and then adding this function in my view for validation:

```
userError: function(e){
        var validationError = e['validationError'];
        var errorContainer = $('#error-container');
        _.each(validationError, function(obj){
            var errorFocus = this.$('#' + obj.name);
            errorFocus.parent().addClass('has-error');
            errorContainer.append('<span id="' + obj.name + '-message">' + obj.message + '<br></span>');
        });

        errorContainer.removeClass('hide').hide().slideDown();
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Backbone has a plugin that make it really easy, see https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation

Her is a simple code just to show how it works. ( CoffeeScript )

Inside your model

```
validation:
   Age:
     required: true
     min: 18
     msg: 'Invalid Age.'

saveNewClient:-> 
    performValidation = true
    if @isValid(performValidation)
        @save()
```

If you model a validation function, when you call the method (`isValid(true)`), backbone will perform all of your validation, and if something is wrong, it will not save.

Try to read about this plugin, this code above is just an simple example.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
saveUser:function(e){

    var me = this;
    var user = new User();
    var firstName = $('.edit-user-form #firstname').val();
    var lastName = $('.edit-user-form #lastname').val();
    var age = $('.edit-user-form #age').val();
    user.set({
        FirstName: firstName,
        LastName: lastName,
        Age: age
    });

if (!user.isValid()) {
                alert("Validation Errors, please fix");
                return; //Do not save
            }else{
      save();      //write the save logic here
   }

}
```

Docs - http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isValid